# Echoing a series of JSON data from php to JavaScript,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I am having a difficulty retrieving a series of json data from php to my JavaScript, file..

Firstly, I have a series of json data stored in an array in php, and echoing each by wrapping it in the for loop to my JavaScript file,

```
<?php

$result = array('{"one": "test","two": "test"}','{"three": "test","four": "test"}');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); ++$i) {
    echo $result[$i];
}

?>
```

in my JavaScript,

```
$.ajax({                              
    url: "visualiser/visualiser_RouteList.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
       console.log(data);        
    } 
});
```

My console does not display anything at all, not recognizing each array element as a json..

but if I send just one array element specifically, for example,

```
echo $result[0];
```

then it successfully displays,

```
Object {one: "test", two: "test"}
```

why can't I pass a series of json data in an array from php in my ajax call?

Comment: The PHP output in this case is: `{"one": "test","two": "test"}{"three": "test","four": "test"}`, which isn't a valid JSON string. See Console for more info on errors.

Comment: Based on what documentation/resource/information is it assumed that concatenating valid json strings results in a valid json string?

Comment: try this :
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); ++$i) {
    $ret = $result[$i];
}
echo json_encode($ret);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are generated malformed JSON. The output of your script is

```
{"one": "test","two": "test"}{"three": "test","four": "test"}
```

When you access the first element of the array only you get

```
{"one": "test","two": "test"}
```

Which is valid.

PHP has [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which will do this work for you, so your code would become

```
$result = array(
    array('one' => 'test', 'two' => 'test'),
    array('three' => 'test', 'four' =>'test')
);

echo json_encode($result);
```

giving the output

```
[{"one":"test","two":"test"},{"three":"test","four":"test"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will output this:

```
{"one": "test","two": "test"}{"three": "test","four": "test"}
```

This is invalid JSON, so obviously will not work. (Try parsing it with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and you'll see.)

You actually need to send the data as an array, so replace your `for` loop with a simple [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) call:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

This will output

```
[{"one": "test","two": "test"},{"three": "test","four": "test"}]
```

This is valid JSON, and can be parsed into a Javascript array.

Comment: are you sitting right next to @danjam :D? It's rare to see answers posted the same second - even more so that are almost the same

Comment: @AD7six I know - precisely the same second!

Comment: heh, I had to double check I hadn't somehow managed to double post there for a second. You know what they say about great minds :>

Answer (score 0):

Also can you this script

```
function doj($json){
$result = json_encode($json);
return  json_decode($result, true);
}

$json = array(
'{"one": "test","two": "test"}',
'{"three": "test","four": "test"}'
);
$j = doj($json);

foreach($j as $k=>$v){
$extractagain = json_decode($v);
print_r($extractagain);
}
```

and the output is:

```
stdClass Object ( [one] => test [two] => test ) stdClass Object ( [three] => test [four] => test )
```